# Дата и время PHP

Tags: php

```
$today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Почему то время выводится с отставанием в 2 часа 50 минут. Как сделать так, чтобы выводилось правильно?

Comment: проверьте настройки сервера. на linux команда date.

Comment: И временную зону

Comment: Как проверить временную зону?

Comment: date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Kiev'); Добавил вот такую строчку в начале, часы теперь нормально, а минуты всё равно отстают на 10

Comment: настройте время на компьютере. Оно не синхронизировано

Answer (score 0):

С отставанием от чего? Если от времени сервера, то ставьте правильную зону в php.ini. Если от времени на вашем локальном компьютере или другом эталонном компьютере, то поставьте на сервер сначала ntp чтобы получать верную дату и время из интернета или настройте вручную через команду date -s для linux